# problem generating php array

Tags: php, arrays

I am generating an php array and then converting it to a xml playlist. converting array to xml is no problem, but i am having problem generating the array. I am getting data from DB and want to use it. My code is like bellow-

```
$songs2008 = get_data("musics", "where year='2008'");
$mysongs = array();
foreach($songs2008 as $k1=>$v1){
    $entry = array(
        "url"=>"songs/main_songs/".$v1[file_name],
        "songname"=>$v1[song_title],
        "artist"=>$v1[artist]
    );
    array_push($mysongs, $entry);
}
```

and the array is -

```
$array = array(
    "settings"=>array(
    "width"=>"316",
        "songs"=>array(
        "albumArt"=>array(
        "url"=>"songs/2008.jpg",
        "entries"=>array(
            "entry"=>$mysongs['0'],
                        "entry"=>$mysongs['1'],
                        "entry"=>$mysongs['2'],
                        ----------------------
                        ----------------------
            )
        )
    )

);
```

Its not working at the entries. the array key is same(entry); so only one showing. is there any solution? any other way to do it? please help.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you can't use 'entry' as an index more than once. Try:

```
"entries" => $mysongs
```

@see: http://php.net/manual/de/language.types.array.php  for further reading an php arrays

But be carefull, you'll propably be running into some problems creating your xml code when using this. For I would bet that you are using the array keys as tag names!

Answer (score 0):

Don't name your array key for "entry"

```
$array = array(
    "settings"=>array(
    "width"=>"316",
        "songs"=>array(
        "albumArt"=>array(
        "url"=>"songs/2008.jpg",
        "entries"=>array(
            $mysongs['0'],
            $mysongs['1'],
            $mysongs['2'],
                        ----------------------
                        ----------------------
            )
        )
    )

);
```

Comment: I am using array keys as xml tag name.